# Setting header search path while adding 3rd party framework into ipad application

Tags: iphone, ipad, ios5

I want to add a 3rd party framework(omnigroup framework for rtf editor) which contains multiple .xcodeproj , into my ipad application. For the proper integration of the framework in the app, how should I set different search paths(header,user and framework) in build settings of projet target. When I tried this, I got different errors like header files
 not found.I am using xcode version 4.2.1,iOS 5 Lion 10.7

I am really struggling with this. Please help !!!

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Can you be more specific? Which 3rd party frameworks? Do you have the source to the frameworks? Generally, you'll want to build the frameworks, and then add the built framework to your project. Then you simply need to do #import <framework/header.h>.

Comment: hai thanks for your response. Actually i am trying to add omnigroup framework for rtf editor into my ipad application. But whenever i compile the project after adding the framework, it throughs lot of errors like OmniBase/OmnibBse.h files not found . I strongly believe that this issues is related with setting the search path in build settings.you can clone the above frame work with a sample project called texteditor.xcworkspace from the https://github.com/omnigroup/OmniGroup.git  link. Please guide me if u have used this framework in ur project...

Answer (score 0):

Did you mean the project target setting?the setting in red rect? [image]

Comment: Hi gage, thanks for your response. I am looking for the same thing which u have mentioned in the screenshot. I am trying to use omnigroup framework for rtf editor in my project.

Comment: @gage,How to give the path format in Header search paths?Please give me sample path format..